# Can we restrict a trigger on table to only perform inserts based on function that is being called by it? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

Is there any way in PostgreSQL where we can restrict the trigger to only do the insert's based on the function that is being called? Say, I created a trigger on fact_activity but whenever I perform any insert's the trigger should execute the function to perform inserts on the table defined in the function only.

--Here's my trigger that executes the function.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON fact_activity
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_function();
```

--Insert function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_function()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
l_part_date TEXT;
l_table_name TEXT;

BEGIN 
  l_part_date := to_char(TO_date(NEW.activity_date_key ::text,'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYY_MM');
  l_table_name := TG_TABLE_NAME ||'_'|| l_part_date;


EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || l_table_name || ' SELECT $1.*' USING NEW;

RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Note: activity_date_key is of integer format (20150512). Hence the conversion.
```

The above script results in a record being inserted in both fact_activity & fact_activity_2015_05. But I only need to insert a record in fact_activity_2015_05.

```
--DDL for the tables:
CREATE TABLE fact_activity
(
  gc_activity_key bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('fact_gc_activity_key_seq'::regclass),
  user_key bigint,
  user_category_key integer,
  user_geographic_region_key integer,
  activity_date_key integer
 );


CREATE TABLE fact_activity_2015_05 ( )
INHERITS  (fact_activity);

-- DML:
INSERT INTO fact_gc_activity(user_key, user_category_key, user_geographic_region_key,activity_date_key)
VALUES (6, 1, 1,20150515);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have only to return NULL instead of NEW.

Comment: Can you bring basic `fact_activity` and `fact_activity_2015_05` ddl ? and an exemple of data you want to insert

Comment: Also, you are calling `insert_function` instead of `partition_insert_function()` !

Comment: I've added the DDL. And sorry about the typo  `insert_function`.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger should return `NULL`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_function()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
l_part_date TEXT;
l_table_name TEXT;

BEGIN 
  l_part_date := to_char(TO_date(NEW.activity_date_key ::text,'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYY_MM');
  l_table_name := TG_TABLE_NAME ||'_'|| l_part_date;


EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || l_table_name || ' SELECT $1.*' USING NEW;

RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```